# Extract open street map data for a specific region

Tags: openstreetmap

I have openstreet data for a specific state. Now I want to extract the data for a city in that city. What sort of tools are available for that?

Answer (score 4):

There are several tools for extracting a region from a file with OpenStreetMap data. Popular options are

- **[Osmosis](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis)** - see the wiki page's "Example Usage" section for examples of extracting bounding boxes and polygon areas
- **[Osmconvert](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmconvert)** - see the ["Clipping based on Longitude and Latitude"](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmconvert#Clipping_based_on_Longitude_and_Latitude) and ["Clipping based on a Polygon"](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmconvert#Clipping_based_on_a_Polygon) sections

In both cases you need to create or obtain a [file](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis/Polygon_Filter_File_Format) containing the city's boundary if you want to accurately extract a polygon area.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try the following web site which is very good at extracting information from open street maps it's the xapi

http://overpass-turbo.eu/

I found it to be good and quick and you can define an area to be searched i.e resizing the boundary box and you can export your retrieved data.